# Error with JSON webhook - Sending data with JSON

Tags: json, api, webhooks

I have problem with webhook, or to be more accurate - with sending data with POST method using endpoint.

I am using this endpoint for POST method:

```
https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Import/AddOrUpdate?ApiKey=apikey_value
```

and this JSON snippet:

```
{
    "Subscribers": [
        {
            "EmailAddress": "email",
            "CustomFields": [
                {
                    "FieldName": "Source",
                    "Value": "source"
                },
                {
                    "FieldName": "Campaign",
                    "Value": "campaign"
                },
                {
                    "FieldName": "Medium",
                    "Value": "medium"
                }
            ],
            "Lists": [
                200468800
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But, after I set automation workflow to trigger transfer data from one database (provider 1) to another base (provider 2) I get error:

```
{
    "ContactsSubmitted": 1,
    "Successes": 0,
    "Failures": [
        {
            "EmailAddress": "email",
            "ErrorCode": 101,
            "Message": "Invalid Email Address"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions? Additional explanation: FieldName is name from **provider 2** and field value is name from **provider 1**.

Answer (score 0):

Missing [some_variable ] is part where my code throws and error. So, the right code is:

```
{
    "Subscribers": [
        {
            "EmailAddress": "[email]",
            "CustomFields": [
                {
                    "FieldName": "Source",
                    "Value": "[source]"
                },
                {
                    "FieldName": "Campaign",
                    "Value": "[campaign]"
                },
                {
                    "FieldName": "Medium",
                    "Value": "[medium]"
                }
            ],
            "Lists": [
                200468800
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```